# Writing some text to the alert

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, alert

Could you please help to handle this case?

I want to write some text to the prompt alert. I used switch_to.alert and send_keys command, but it does not work.

```
   baseUrl = "https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/javascript-alert-box-demo.html"
   driver = webdriver.Chrome()
   driver.maximize_window()
   driver.get(baseUrl)

   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Click for Prompt Box')]").click()
   alert1 = driver.switch_to.alert.send_keys("some text")
   alert1.accept()
```

I get this error:

**alert1.accept()**

**AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'accept'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to get the alert first and then call send_keys and accept methods.

```
alert1 = driver.browser.switch_to.alert
alert1.send_keys("some text")
alert1.accept()
```

If you are still getting the NoneType error, may be add an explicit wait for the alert to appear.

```
 WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.alert_is_present(),
                               'Timed out waiting for PA creation ' +
                               'confirmation popup to appear.')
```

Due to [existing](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/7017) [issues](https://github.com/w3c/webdriver/issues/385) with Selenium as of this writing, the `alert.send_keys` is not working. Below is a workaround using [PyAutoGUI](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/)

```
import time
import pyautogui

baseUrl = "https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/javascript-alert-box-demo.html"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(baseUrl)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Click for Prompt Box')]").click()
alert1 = driver.switch_to.alert
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.typewrite('Hello world!')     
time.sleep(1)
alert1.accept()
```

Comment: good answer... the `send_keys` method returns `None` hens the error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'accept'

Comment: @Naveen Thanks for the reply.
When I try to get the alert first and then call send_keys and accept methods, I get no error and accept is performed, but nothing is entered into an alert input field.
Waiting also does not help, there are errors, but nothing is being typed.

Comment: I tried to execute the solution in Chrome and i see what you mean. There seems to be some existing bug pending with W3C. https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/7017 https://github.com/w3c/webdriver/issues/385

Comment: I've updated the solution with a workaround i've tested and it is working.

Comment: Hi @Naveen. I have run into another problem.
Pyautogui works fine on a windows machine, but on the MacBook, I have the same problem, there are no errors, but nothing was typed.
Do you have any idea?
macOS Catalina
Version: 10.15.1

Comment: Seems to be a possible solution in this thread: https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/247#issuecomment-437668855